# Execute User-Application e.g (Notepad) from UMDF driver

Tags: c, umdf

The main objective is to know if there is a way to start or execute any user-mode application from UMDF (User Mode Driver Framework) event. It doesn't matter about the event. Any event may work e.g. DriverEntry, DeviceAttach

I am working on a solution to start an application, when the windows boots up.

1. I have tried start from driver, but not found any way to include 'process.h' library, which have a function call 'system('app_name') to start. But no luck
2. I have tried injecting DLL with injdrv [here](https://github.com/wbenny/injdrv)!, but found no way out

I highly appreciate if you suggest any work-around. 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Directly from UMDF2.0, I don't think that you can.
What you can do is to use Task Scheduler to run any.EXE that you want with an Event Trigger.

The event will be "fired" from the UMDF (or Even from KMDF), you can use ETW or Windows Event log.